# how to implement audio recorder in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, audio-recording

I just want to implement audio recording tool in our application.The functionality is as follows.

Record an audio through microphone(voice recording)
stop that audio
saving that audio
generate embed code for the same audio

I appreciate your suggessions to implement this.

thanks very much

Comment: Also, since C# itself is quite poor in audio controls - which media framework do you want to use (XNA / DirectX / nAudio / ...)?

Comment: This topic has been treated several times in stackoverflow, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64010/how-does-one-record-audio-from-a-javascript-based-webapp

Comment: @CharithJ: It's in the question: _i need to create a web page that when a user clicks [...]_

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET on its own is not suited for this kind of application. If you want users to be able to record audio on your website, you could take a look at Silverlight 4.0 ([vid](http://silverlight.net/learn/videos/silverlight-4-beta-videos/access-web-camera-microphone/)).

See also this question:
[Recording Audio From Web Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911008/recording-audio-from-web-page)

If that's not what you need, please explain your intended purpose more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

This should be done in flash or silverlight. This has not a lot to do with c#.

See http://activeden.net/item/sound-recorder/104191