# How to Create a Simple C# Audio/Voice recorder in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to implement audio recorder in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324954/how-to-implement-audio-recorder-in-asp-net)

I need help, i need to create a web page that when a user clicks on the Record Button it starts recording the users voice. then a Pause/Stop button which pauses or stops the recording then a Play button where the user can hear what his/her voice sounds like. then maybe a Save button so that the user can save their voice recording. Could anyone please help me what can i do. how do i start I am very new to programming and have been battling for a week to find help on google.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324954/how-to-implement-audio-recorder-in-asp-net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324954/how-to-implement-audio-recorder-in-asp-net)