# GWT audio recording

Tags: java, gwt, audio, audio-recording

Are there any options for recording audio in a GWT application ?

Options seem to include flex, perhaps a java applet or some other form of flash ?

Comment: And your question is? You can use an applet or a Flash application to record audio, but that itself has nothing to do with GWT.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately it doesn't appear that there is any way to record audio using just JavaScript currently, so it won't be possible using GWT alone (since the GWT compiler only produces JavaScript).

However, Mozilla's Jetpack project includes a proposed [Audio API](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Labs/Jetpack/JEP/18) that may make it possible.  Keep in mind that this is a cutting-edge feature and will probably not be widely supported for a very long time.

This answer might be helpful, since it's asking a similar question: [How does one record audio from a Javascript based webapp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64010/how-does-one-record-audio-from-a-javascript-based-webapp)

Answer (score 1):

For our GWT web application we use a Java applet made by Javasonics. They have a free (with limitations) version that you can use. It works very well and supports several audio formats. The applet worked without problems on Windows, Linux and Mac.

You can control the applet using JavaScript. In your GWT client code, you will have to use JSNI to interface between the real JavaScript code and your GWT code.

However, it seems that there is a bug in GWT that makes the applet display on top of dialogs and it is quite annoying. We dealt with this issue by setting the applet's visibility to false when displaying dialog boxes.